# Scanning small artwork to pdf or tiff?

Tags: pdf, scanning, tiff

I'm scanning a bunch of custom greeting cards (think scrapbook style).  I've been scanning to pdf since many of them have multiple pages per card.

I'm wondering if I should also scan a tiff from the front side of the card for later (converted) use on websites, etc.  Or if converting the pdf to an image is good enough.

I did a test, and the pdf converted to an image looks good.  But I just want to make sure that sounds like a good idea.

I'd really appreciate any advice or comments you guys might have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it is a high quality scan, you can just extract the image from PDF later, so why make extra work for yourself!

If however you are making average quality scans, you may also want a "backup" high quality image... but again if the original scan is high enough, I think you are already doing enough.

Comment: Most of these cards are store card size or smaller.  I've been scanning between 600-1200 dpi.  

They won't really be printed or anything, but for archival purposes, I wanted a high quality scan.  I hope that's enough.

Answer (score 1):

definitely save the images in high-quality if you want to use them later for other purposes (storage is cheap :).

you will loose quality if you extract them form PDF later.